# Deployd dpd failed to start MongoDB $PATH problem despite having $PATH set; --mongod option also does nothing

Tags: mongodb, path, deployd, dpd

so I have this problem where whenever I try to run any variation of dpd command such as "dpd -d" "dpd -d --mongod "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe" or "dpd -p 5500 app.dpd" I constantly get the error: (I am using Windows 10)

```
deployd CLI version 2.0.2
starting deployd
Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongod option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html)
```

Yes, I do have mongod directory in my PATH.

I have checked and my PATH variables for user and global are set to the /bin direction of mongod.
I have tried running it while mongod.exe is running and when it's closed, setting the PATH by the %PATH% command etc. I have ran out of options at this point. I did manage to run the dashboard once but there was 404 [Object object] only written there and then I couldn't reopen it again. Any ideas? None of the solutions from SO worked for me so far.

Comment: Have you logged out and/or rebooted after changing PATH?

Comment: @Oleg Yes, I tried it multiple times now. Still same error.